# Android Studio won't start, libjli.dylib too short

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, preview

Cannot open Android Studio 3.0 Preview, I have Android Studio 2.3 running in the same machine, Java 1.6 AND Java 1.8 installed, `JAVA_HOME` configured to the 1.8 version. Still this new Android Studio version doesn't open.

Trying to open it directly from the `studio` file, I got the following error:

```
allVms required 1.8*,1.8+
Cannot load JVM bundle: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 "dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib: file too short
        /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib: file too short" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle is damaged or missing necessary resources., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib, NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib: file too short
        /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib: file too short, NSBundlePath=/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “OpenJDK 8” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.}
```

Taking closer attention to this line:

```
libjli.dylib: file too short, NSBundlePath=/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “OpenJDK 8” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.}
```

I tried find some problem with the bundled JDK, looks good, the archive downloaded has no issues. Anyone ever had something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was about to post the issue when I found the problem.

For me the issue was that `libjli.dylib` file in MacOS folder, **it's not a file, but a symbolic link to the real file**, but when I decompressed it, it lost its properties as a symbolic link, and became an empty file. Deleting the following file, and creating a new symbolic link solved the issue.

```
/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib
```

this ^ guy links to this:

```
/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib
```

Given that your Android Studio app location is `/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app` as mine, the following commands solved the issue for me:

First remove:

```
rm /Applications/Android\ Studio\ 3.0\ Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib
```

Then create a new link:

```
ln -s /Applications/Android\ Studio\ 3.0\ Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib /Applications/Android\ Studio\ 3.0\ Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib
```

Just **open Android Studio as usual**.

Comment: Oh my god! I can`t believe It`s finally working! I`ve read all the internet and nothing worked! You sir deserve a medal!!!

Comment: This worked (removal and relink) for me too on Android Studio 3.2 Preview, but the first file was not a symbolic link.

Comment: This issue came up for me again and finally I know why it happened in the first place. As an ex-Windows user I was looking for a replacement for Total commander, and started using Double commander for handling files. As it turns out, this was not a great idea, when I copied the Android Studio bundle to the `Applications` folder with Finder, it worked perfectly, but before, when I did it using Double commander, I kept getting this issue. So I guess Double commander removed the symlink property from the file